# ICommand - Who invoke the Execute?

Tags: .net, wpf

As per topic, who invokes the Execute?

In my code, I bind a Command to a button click. (For some reason, SO does not allow me to put XAML codes here...)

I'm curious how/what goes behind that actually triggers the Execute(). From the stack, it seems to be calling:
 1. Button.OnClick
 2. Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick
 3. Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource
 4. ActionCommand.Execute

Even after looking at the trace, I still don't quite get it. Can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: Commands are invoked by the runtime lying underneath WPF. You should not get any stack trace when checking on the `Execute` method

Comment: To put in XAML code paste the code then highlight it and hit the button in the toolbar that looks like `{ }`, that will format the text as code and not strip out what it thinks is illigal HTML tags.